# Shell - Remove duplicate Paragraphs

Tags: shell, awk

I have a .sh file with a lot of duplicates paraphrase inside. Now I need to remove these duplicates and only keep one

For example

```
**startkeyword**
  today is good
  how are you
  apple
**endKeyword**
**startkeyword**
  today is good
  how are you
  apple
**endKeyword**
**startkeyword**
 do you like apple
 I like apple
**endKeyword**
**startkeyword**
  today is good
  how are you
**endKeyword**
**startkeyword**
  today is good
  how are you
  apple
**endKeyword**
```

the result should be:

```
**startkeyword**
  today is good
  how are you
  apple
**endKeyword**
**startkeyword**
 do you like apple
 I like apple
**endKeyword**
**startkeyword**
  today is good
  how are you
**endKeyword**
```

How can I do it within a .sh file? free to use sed, awk, or tr

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: I am not understanding what you are talking about . You can use  `awk '!visited[$0]++'  filename.txt` It doesn't give the exact output but removes every duplicate line.

Comment: @Cyrus - that answer is very good and a rare example of `RS=''` (e.g. [Multiple-Line Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html#Multiple-Line))  Would be worth a vote. Though I understand your choice based on lack of code example provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind removing asterisks `**`

```
awk -v RS='[*][*]\n[*][*]' '{gsub(/[*]|\n$/,""); if(!visited[$0]++) print $0}' file
```

Output

```
startkeyword
  today is good
  how are you
  apple
endKeyword
startkeyword
 do you like apple
 I like apple
endKeyword
startkeyword
  today is good
  how are you
endKeyword
```